# pdflatex and pstricks

Tags: latex, pdflatex, pstricks

I normally use pdflatex to convert papers written as tex files to a pdf for publishing.  With pdflatex any figures in the tex file can be PNG, PDF etc but not PostScript.  Now I am writing a paper where I have some figures created with pstricks and that means I have to use latex to generate the a dvi file and then dvips and ps2pdf to obtain the final pdf file.
I cannot generate the pstricks figures separately because they contain citations and references to sections in the paper and if I use the sequence latex->dvips->ps2pdf for the whole tex file I cannot have other figures as PNG or PDF, they have to be converted to PostScript.
Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Have a look at the `auto-pst-pdf` package

Comment: That works prefectly, thanks.

Comment: Hm ... not so perfect when I try to use \ref{eq:whatever} to reference an equation defined outside my pspicture figure.